# App crashes on iPhone but not simulator or iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have developed an app for the iPhone and everything is going well. Today i decided to prep it for the upcoming iOS 7 launch, and the app worked as intended until I tried it on my iPhone 5. Whenever it crashes it throws some exc_bad_access codes. 
It doesn't crash in the simulator or on my iPad which is running iOS 6.1. 
I hope you guys can help me.

Btw, i get different exc_bad_access codes every time, but this is one of them.
http://gyazo.com/43716488eb120e44e74f76cd4d659076

Comment: Did you enable it to run on iOS 7?

Comment: Yes i did. The app itself runs fine, and other functions of the app works as well, it's only 1 or 2 things that crashes. (These 2 functions works in the simulator/ on the ipad.)

Comment: Please post; i) Backtrace (ideally as text) and ii) corresponding code as part of the question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have thread-related race conditions. Note how it's crashing in thread 7? Race conditions will express themselves differently on different hardware since the timing can be dramatically different.

`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is a UIKit method that must run on the main thread. In your case, it's running on thread 7, which is itself probably the cause of your problem. I suspect you're doing something like calling `reloadData` on a background thread.

Note that you're also directly accessing your ivars rather than using accessors. That tends to make threading problems harder to track down and manage. You should always be using accessors except in `init`, inside of accessors, and in `dealloc`.

Comment: You are a very wise man.. or experienced programmer! ;) 
Nomatter, you were right in saying that the culprit was an action on a background thread! 
Thank you.